# iText 7 inserting unwanted space after italic span

Tags: java, formatting, itext

I've noticed that iText 7 (sometimes) auto-inserts a space between two pieces of text if the first is italicized (i.e. "*like*this" -> "*like* this"). The example below illustrates my problem:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Text;

public class PdfItalic {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new File("italic.pdf")));
        Document doc = new Document(document, PageSize.A4);

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.add(new Text("abc").setItalic());
        p.add(new Text("def"));

        doc.add(p);
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Which looks as follows when opened in a PDF viewer (and no, it is not a kerning problem; when I copy the text in a PDF viewer, it also copies that ghost space):

[image: Unwanted space between "abc" and "def"]

I want to avoid this behavior at any cost. How can I prevent iText 7 from inserting those misplaces spaces?